# Control a VB.NET application via webpage

Tags: vb.net, web

I have a VB.NET application (that I may refactor as a windows service) that I'd like to control via a web page. On the same machine are running both that application and the apache webserver that runs that webpage.

This application is the "audio engine" and the users could be able to control it remotely via a specific webpage. The idea is: the user clicks a button on the webpage and it calls a function on the VB.NET app.

The VB.NET app executes the function and then replies to the webpage with the value returned.

What could be the simplest way to implement this functionality?

I prefer to avoid an ASP.NET project because I have already that application done.

Comment: There are probably a number of approaches depending on the use case.  For something asynchronous the web app could write to a DB and the application could monitor the DB for new records, perform the process, and update the DB.  The web app would just check the DB when a page is loaded.  For something more synchronous the application could listen on a port or socket and the web app could connect and send/receive messages.

Comment: Would it make sense to add a reference to this vb.net application to your asp.net project making all functionality available (depending on access modifiers of course)?